# Prove: if $x_0$ is a function of $Ax=b$, then there exist some generalized inverse matrix of A, G, s.t. $x_0 = Gb$

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-inverse

Suppose $x_0$ is a solution of $Ax=b$, where $b\neq0$. How to prove that $x_0 = Gb$, where $G$ is a generalized inverse matrix of A?

This is the Lemma 9.3 of Linear Algebra and Matrix. Here is proof, but I just cannot get it.

The last line says $x_0$ has the form of $u + GA(x_0 - u)$, but I do not understand why $u + GA(x_0 - u) = G^*b$ for some generalized inverse of $A$.

> Lemma 9.3 Let $A x=b$ be a consistent linear system, where $A$ is $m \times n$ and at least one of the following two conditions hold: $(a) \rho(\boldsymbol{A})=n$ (i.e., A is of full column rank$),$ or $(b) \boldsymbol{b} \neq 0 .$ Then, $\boldsymbol{x}_{0}$ is a solution to $\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{b}$ if and only if $\boldsymbol{x}_{0}=\boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{b}$ for
>   some generalized inverse $\boldsymbol{G}$ of $\boldsymbol{A}$
>   Proof. If $\boldsymbol{x}_{0}=\boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{b}$ for some generalized inverse of $\boldsymbol{A},$ then Definition 9.2 itself ensures that $x_{0}$ is a solution.
>
> Suppose (a) holds. Then $A$ has full column rank, which means that $A x=b$ has a unique solution (Theorem 9.4 ). This solution must be of the form $G b,$ where $G$ is a generalized inverse of $A,$ because $G b$ is a solution.
>
> Now suppose that (b) holds. That is, $\boldsymbol{b} \neq \mathbf{0}$. If $\boldsymbol{x}_{0}$ is a solution for $\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{b},$ then $\boldsymbol{x}_{0}=\boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{b}+\left(\boldsymbol{I}_{m}-\boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{A}\right) \boldsymbol{u}$ for some vector $\boldsymbol{u} \in \Re^{n} .$ since $\boldsymbol{b}=\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}_{0},$ we have
>   $$\boldsymbol{x}_{0}=\boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}_{0}+\left(\boldsymbol{I}_{m}-\boldsymbol{G}\boldsymbol{A}\right) \boldsymbol{u}=\boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{G}\boldsymbol{A}\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{0}-\boldsymbol{u}\right)$$

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the authors are hinting at, but one can easily prove that $x_0=Gb$ for some $G$ by mapping basis vectors appropriately. Let $A$ be $m\times n$, its rank is $r$ and $\{Ax_0,\ldots,Ax_{r-1}\}$ be a basis of the column space of $A$. Let $b_i=Ax_i$ (so that $b_0=b$) and let $\{b_0,\ldots,b_{m-1}\}$ be a full basis of $\mathbb R^m$. Define $Gb_i$ to be $x_i$ if $i<r$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $AGA=A$ and $Gb=x_0$.

Comment: @user1551 Than you. How to prove the existence of $G$ so that $Gb_i = x_i$ for any $i<r$?

Comment: We have already *defined* it to be so.

Comment: @user1551 yes. But why it is well defined?

Comment: Why isn't it well defined? You pick a basis of the domain, map the basis vectors to some specific points, and extend the mapping by linearity. This is a usual way of defining linear maps. I don't see any ambiguity here.